# Fastest way to zero out a vector<vector<bool> >

Tags: c++, vector

I've tried something like this:

```
vector<bool> x(10, 0);
vector<vector<bool> > hello(10, x);

/*some modifications on hello*/

memset(&hello, 0, sizeof(hello));
```

And my program compiles, but it breaks. Any idea how I can do this operation as quickly as possible? I know that the memset probably isn't working because of the nested vector, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this task.

Comment: is the second dimension always 10 in size? I mean always always?

Comment: You should be careful using `memset` in c++, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975916/should-c-programmer-avoid-memset Even if it didn't result in a runtime error, you would have best case cleared the outer vector completely and leaked some memory on the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this, which reuses the `x` variable you declared in the question.

```
std::fill(hello.begin(), hello.end(), x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(auto& bv : hello) 
    std::fill(begin(bv), end(bv), false);
```

Or if you want to use `x` as the prototype

```
std::fill(begin(hello), end(hello), x);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code you have, I'd write …

```
for( auto& v : hello ) { v = x; }
```

assuming `x` has remained as all-zeros. It's clear enough and avoids dragging in `<algorithm>`.

Hewever, it will probably be faster to change the representation of your bit matrix, from a vector of vectors to a single vector, or if it's fixed size, to a single `bitset`.