# What is the best way of clearing a char array in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I've been searching for ways of emptying a char array in C/C++. I have come up with this code:

```
char testName[20];   

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(testName); ++i)
{
  testName[i] = (char)0;
}
```

It has been working for a while now but when I try to `strlen`the result is always two more than the typed in word. For instance I input the word `dog` the output would be five. Why is that so? Is my char array not cleared?

Here is my code:

```
char testName[20];
void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    Serial.println("Waiting for name...");
    index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(testName); ++i)
    {
        testName[i] = (char)0;
    }
    while(Serial.available())
    {
      char character = Serial.read();
      testName[index] = character;
      index++;
    }
    Serial.print("Name received: ");
    Serial.println(testName);
    Serial.print("The sentence entered is ");
    Serial.print(strlen(testName));
    Serial.println(" long");
    delay(1000);
  } 
  delay(1000);
}
```

Screenshot of the output:

[image: Screenshot of the output]

Output as text:

```
Name received: dog

The sentence entered is 5 characters long
```

Comment: Are you sure you do not also get `\r\n` at the end of the input?

Comment: have you stepped through the debugger? maybe there is a carriage return and line feed.

Comment: You can't empty arrays in C++.

Comment: The best way is to not use char arrays at all. Instead use std::string.

Comment: Take a read of `memset`'s documentation.

Comment: You could have been a little bit more investigative and simply wrote a loop to see what each character was in your array when you got the "strange" `strlen` result.

Comment: how about `testName[0] = '\0';` ?

Comment: @manni66 why on earth this advice?

Comment: @SergeyA why on earth this question?

Comment: Answering the question as asked, the best way to clear char array in C++ is to use `std::fill(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), '\0')`

Comment: @manni66 because your suggestion is plain wrong.

Comment: @manni66, no. Char arrays often are much more appropriate than `std::string`. Also, your language is not nice.

Comment: @manni66 the OP is talking about char arrays, not about `std::vector` or `std::string`.

Comment: @SergeyA I don't want to be nice. cahr arrays are not appropriate. Don't allwas insist on programming C in C++!

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes, and the advice is to not use it!

Comment: @manni66 your comment violates stack overflow policy (and reported as such). You can be whatever you want to be, but not here. On technical side, you obviously are not aware of drawbacks of `std::string` and are oblivious to a lot of use cases. I suggest you educate yourself before you talk expletives.

Comment: @WernerHenze  You are a genius. Thank you!

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez I had `Both NL & CR` in my Serial Monitor. I changed it to `No line encoding` and its all good now. Thank you!

Comment: @SergeyA: Now I'm curious. Which part of the Stack Overflow policy is violated by suggesting the use of `std::string` in C++?

Comment: @SergeyA why do you claim that "Char arrays often are much more appropriate than std::string"? The majority of C++ programmers instead claim that strings are often much more appropriate than char arrays.

Comment: @ChristianHackl the deleted one. He used expletives there.

Comment: @Xam I am not sure about 'majority'. But if you interested in such cases, you can ask the sepatate question, and I will gladly answer.

Comment: @SergeyA: I see...

Comment: @SergeyA yes. that would be nice. I still learning C++ and among different answers and opinions given in SO, I read many C++ programmers that recommend to use `std::string`.

Comment: @xam ask the question on stack overflow, you can post link here in comments so that I can see it

Comment: For the purpose of saving serial data in a character _array_, there is not need for "clearing a char array".  The _array_ can be made a _string_ with a single _null character_.  May be useful for debugging though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use C style arrays in modern C++. When you require a fixed size array, use `std::array` instead. From a memory storage point of view, they are identical.

You can then clear the array with: `myarray.fill('\0')`

Answer (score 9):

If your definition of "emptying char array" is *set all elements of an array to zero*, you can use [`std::memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset).

This will allow you to write this instead of your clear loop:

```
const size_t arraySize = 20;  // Avoid magic numbers!
char testName[arraySize];
memset(&(testName[0]), 0, arraySize);
```

As for "strange" results of `strlen()`:

[`strlen(str)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) returns *"(...) the number of characters in a character array whose first element is pointed to by `str` up to and not including the first null character"*. That means, it will count characters until it finds zero.

Check content of strings you pass to `strlen()` - you may have white characters there (like `\r` or `\n`, for example), that were read from the input stream.

Also, an advice - consider using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of plain `char` arrays.

---

Small note: `memset()` is often optimized for high performance. If this in not your requirement, you can also use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) which is a more C++ - like way to fill array of anything:

```
char testName[arraySize];
std::fill(std::begin(testName), std::end(testName), '\0');
```

[`std::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) (and `std::end`) works well with arrays of compile-time size.

---

Also, to answer @SergeyA's comment, I suggest to read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975916/should-c-programmer-avoid-memset) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1976140/2812864).

Comment: Downvoting for unsafe `memset`. Still downvoting after edit, since `std::fill` is - guess what - optimized too! There is NO REASON to use memset in C++ program.

Comment: @SergeyA I was already updating my answer with an `std::fill` version. But `std::memset` is often used because of its optimized implementations, so it definitely should be mentioned. I recommend using `std::string`, but since we have a code with plain `char` arrays here, wrong usage of `memset` is the least concern IMHO.

Comment: Like I said above, `std::fill` is at the same performance level as `memset`, only safer. If you do not believe me, check the codegen yourself.

Comment: std::fill can not be optimised away; memset can.  I'm pretty sure that memset is also allowed to write chunks larger than a byte at a time; while std::fill is not.

Comment: @UKMonkey yes I confirm, many `memset` implementations are highly optimized, some even use spezialized instruction sets specific to the platform, and often calls to `memset` are directly inlined.

Comment: @SergeyA I would never blame somebody who proposes `memset` when the task is to set the content of the C-style `char` array.

Comment: @SergeyA because allowed to and "this compiler does or doesn't" are different; especially when it doesn't

Comment: @MichaelWalz and `std::fill` is either specialized to use `memset` for POD types, or optimizer generates optimized code on the fly recognizing the pattern.

Comment: @UKMonkey you are contradicting yourself. If you are talking about common optimizations, I just showed how `std::fill` is optimized the same way as `memset`. If you are talking about the fact that optimizations are not mandatory, than `memset` is not required to be optimized either. Stick to one.

Comment: @SergeyA cppreference states very explicitly that it will make end-begin assignments;  and on top of that; there is no statement there that the compiler can optimise away the entire call if it's not use in the case of 'as-is' (so you could use it to wipe passwords).  memset however DOES state that it can be optimised away.  To me this seems like a bug in the implementation of std::fill; or an error in cppreference.  And I'm not contradicting myself; as I'm talking about what the compiler is allowed to do; not what they do.

Comment: @SergeyA As I said - I suggested `memset` because of the code which manipulates plain `char` arrays. I included ``std::fill` as more elegant and safer solution, designed specifically to be used in C++ (as opposed to `memset`, which comes from C). No reason to downvote this answer IMHO.

Comment: @SergeyA `std::fill` is less safe than `std::memset` because you can accidentally pass iterators that point to separate ranges, and end up with undefined behaviour. `std::memset` does not have a possibility for that bug.

Comment: @user2079303 with std::memset you can just pass random pointer and size. You can also manage to call it for non-pod types. But of course, `std::fill` with ranges would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another quick way of filling an array with zeroes, in initialization only:

```
char testName[20] = {};
```

same as

```
char testName[20] = {0};
```

Since it is a C99 feature, compiler could complain with the following

```
warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces
```

More [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization).

Anyway, looking at the OP code, there's no need at all of initializing/filling the array, it could be better like this:

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 20
char testName[MAX_LENGTH];
void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available())
  {
    Serial.println("Waiting for name...");
    index = 0;
    while(Serial.available())
    {
      if(index < MAX_LENGTH) 
          testName[index++] = Serial.read();
    }
    if(index < MAX_LENGTH)
    {
      testName[index] = 0;
      Serial.print("Name received: ");
      Serial.println(testName);
      Serial.print("The sentence entered is ");
      Serial.print(strlen(testName));
      Serial.println(" long");
    }
    else
      Serial.print("Name too long ...");

    delay(1000);
  } 
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Only good at the point of definition. Cannot be used elsewhere.

Comment: You cannot "clear" existing arrays with zeros this way.

Comment: I'd delete this answer, it's really pointless here, because the OP obviously wants to fill the array inside his loop.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Why is this answer pointless? This is useful, relevant information that people working with raw buffers need to know.

Comment: Question says: *emptying a char array in C++*, code explicitly shows that clear needs to be performed on a already existing array and the very first sentence of this answer is: *"(...) quick way of filling an array with zeroes, **in initialization only**"*...

Comment: I think my answer fits the OP need, given the code posted, not the question.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek The first thing the `OP`'s code does is fill an array **immediately** after definition. If the `OP` employed this answer then that loop would have been unnecessary. This is not the *whole* answer to the question but it is certainly very relevant and worth of being included among the answers.

Comment: In C, note that `char testName[20] = {};` can warn: "warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Wpedantic]"

Comment: It's C99, yes. Thanks anyway, I will add this to the answer.

Comment: Btw - please keep this answers. StackOverflow has a wider audience tgan just the OP

Comment: I agree with you, @doron. I'll keep it.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity. The OP example is an Arduino sketch. Assuming here that the input is taken through the built-in Serial Monitor of the Arduino IDE. At the bottom of the Serial Monitor window is a pop-up menu where the line ending can be selected as:

- No line ending
- newline
- Carriage return
- Both NL & CR

Whatever option is selected in this menu is appended to whatever is entered in the box at the top of the Serial Monitor when the Send button is clicked or the return key is hit. So the extra two characters are most certainly the result of having the "Both NL & CR" menu option selected.

Picking the "No line ending" option will solve the problem.

FWIW, in this application, the array does not need to be "cleared". Just append a '\0' char to the last char received to make it a C-string and all will be good.