# Why is memset causing problem despite being used on built-in types?

Tags: c++, arrays, memset, built-in-types

I am very new to `C++` and was making a submission to [this](http://codeforces.com/contest/1102/problem/B) problem on `Codeforces` and suddenly found that using `memset()` was causing `Wrong answer` to one of the test cases.

Here is the test case:

```
Input:
4 4
3 3 3 5
Participant's output
NO
Jury's answer
YES
1 2 3 4 
Checker comment
wrong answer Jury has the answer but the participant hasn't
```

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int check_if_painted[5010][5010];
int input_array[5010];
int main(){

    int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;

    int occurence_count[n];//Keeps track of the total no. of occurences of an element in the input_array.
    memset(occurence_count,0,sizeof(occurence_count));
    /*
    The following loop checks if the occurrence of a particular 
    element is not more than k. If the occurence>k the "NO" is printed and program ends.
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin>>input_array[i];
        ++occurence_count[input_array[i]];
        if(occurence_count[input_array[i]]>k){
            cout<<"NO";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout<<"YES\n";


    /*
    The following loop uses the array check_if_painted as a counter to check if the particular 
    occurrence of an element has been painted with a colour from 1 to k or not. 
    If some previous occurrence of this particular element has been painted with f%k+1, 
    then f is incremented until we encounter any value(of `f%k+1`) from 1 to k that hasn't been 
    used yet to colour and then we colour this element with that value by printing it.
    */
    int f=0;//
    /*
    f is a global value which increments to a very large value but f%k+1 is used 
    to restrict it within the 1 to k limit(both inclusive). So, we are able to check 
    if any previous occurrence of the current element has already been coloured with the value f%k+1 or not.  
    which essentially is 1 to k.
    */ 
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        while(check_if_painted[input_array[i]][f%k+1]>0){
            ++f;
        }
        cout<<f%k+1<<" ";
        ++check_if_painted[input_array[i]][f%k+1];
        ++f;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But, when I tried the below code, It was **accepted successfully**.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int check_if_painted[5010][5010];
int input_array[5010];
int occurence_count[5010];
int main(){

    int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;




    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin>>input_array[i];
        ++occurence_count[input_array[i]];
        if(occurence_count[input_array[i]]>k){
            cout<<"NO";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout<<"YES\n";



    int f=0;

    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        while(check_if_painted[input_array[i]][f%k+1]>0){
            ++f;
        }
        cout<<f%k+1<<" ";
        ++check_if_painted[input_array[i]][f%k+1];
        ++f;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975916/should-c-programmer-avoid-memset#1975961) post on SO, I found that `memset` works well on built-in types. So, why is it causing the problem in my case when it has been used on an `int` array which is a default type.

Also, I've also read that `std::fill()` is better alternative and read in [this](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0360/) post that `memset` is a dangerous function, then why is it still in use?

Comment: Technically, none of them are "right" because C++ doesn't allow arrays to be declared that use dynamic sizes. The size must be a constant expression.

Comment: Sorry, what is the actual problem? `memset` does behave as [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset)...

Comment: Check the value that `sizeof(h)` produces. I'll bet it's wrong.

Comment: @PeteBecker for `n=5`, it gives `40`. Shouldn't this be right?

Comment: The value of h is different in both versions. `ll h[n]` or `ll h[5010]`. Also `h[n]` is not valid C++ so I am not sure how it works with `sizeof(h)` especially since `h[n]` is a runtime thing while `sizeof(h)` is a compile time thing. How can `sizeof(h)` work in this situation.

Comment: Read also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging with `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). You might be interested in [watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html)

Comment: @MartinYork -- from the comment, it looks like `sizeof(h)` is giving the correct result. Yes, it's ordinarily a compile-time thing, but it could recognize a runtime-sized array and handle that correctly.

Comment: If a compiler supports VLA's as an extension, then `sizeof` is a run time thing.   That's part of the requirement for VLA's in C.      However, if the code is compiled using a C++ compiler that diagnoses usage of VLAs, the code will fail to compile - which would normally mean not giving the required answer in an automated check.

Comment: @MartinYork As far as I know about `memset` sets each of the bytes with the value `0` (above) then how is it different even when sizeof(h) is giving the right result in run-time?

Comment: Can't understand the downvotes here when something has been asked for the purpose of learning.

Comment: The downvotes are probably because you dumped two large blocks of code with poor variable names, unclear semantics and no comments, forcing us to visually diff them and try to work out what `memset` has to do with it, rather than performing some debugging and producing a [mcve]. And because there are more differences than just the presence of `memset`. Can't really see how this question will be useful to future visitors, sorry. (Just because you posted something "for the purpose of learning" does not automatically mean you are immune from downvoting!)

Comment: BTW, your `typedef long long ll;` makes your code unreadable, IMHO.

Comment: The comments are a great improvement (and I know that this is intended for an online judge that doesn't give a crap what the code looks like) but a rule of thumb: any time you find yourself needing to add a comment to explain what code does, ask yourself "Is there any way I can improve the code to make it self descriptive?" The code itself should tell the majority of the story. Comments should be a add-on to provide greater context, assumptions, and other information that cannot be inferred from the code.

Comment: Example: A reader should require a comment to explain the purpose of `f` and  not have to remind themselves constantly of the meaning of `f`. The identifier used in place of `f` should contain this information, at least in an abbreviated mnemonic. That said, for some well-known algorithms, single letter variables can take on a well-known meaning and should be used because it is expected from the literature.

Comment: @user4581301 I hope the code is way more understandable now. I couldn't find any better name for `f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with `memset`. Your code is going outside the boundaries of your array, plain and simple.

In your input case you have n = 4 and k = 4, so `occurrence_count` is 4 elements long (its valid indexes go from 0 to 3 inclusive). Then, you do

```
    cin>>input_array[i];
    ++occurence_count[input_array[i]];
```

Given that the last value is 4, you are ultimately doing `++occurence_count[4]`, which goes out of the boundaries of your array. This is undefined behavior, which in your case manifests as incrementing memory not belonging to that array, which most probably doesn't start to 0 and messes up the later check.

The problem is not seen in your second code snippet, as you make `occurence_count` 5010 elements big and zero-inizialized by default as it is a global variable.

Now, if you are going to count occurrences of array values, of course sizing the occurrences array to be as big as the number of elements is wrong - that's the count of numbers you are going to read (and it would be fine to size `input_array`), *not* the maximum value you can read. Given that the array element *values* are from 1 to 5000, the occurrences array must be either sized 5001 (keeping values as they are), or sized 5000 (decrementing the values you read by 1 to index such array).

(In general, be careful as all indexes in the problem text are 1 based, while indexes in C++ are 0 based; you risk off-by-one errors if you reason with the problem indexes and then use them as C indexes, unless you over-size arrays by one and ignore the 0-th element).

---

Finally, some extra remarks:

- if you compile with enough warnings enabled or with a recent enough compiler, it'll rightly complain as `memset` is not defined or that it is being implicitly defined (with an incorrect prototype, BTW); you should `#include <string.h>` to use `memset`;
- as *@Nicol Bolas* went to a great length to explain in his answer, you are using VLAs (variable length arrays) when declaring a local array with size known only at runtime (`int occurence_count[n]`).

  VLAs aren't standard C++, so they aren't well specified, several compilers don't support them and, in general, are problematic in a number of ways (mostly, you shouldn't really allocate an unknown amount of data on the stack, which is generally small);

  You should probably avoid them in favor of `std::vector` or, given that the problem provides you an upper limit of both colors and elements (5000), just static arrays.